# Stop Debugging does not work the way it should VS 2012

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I recently came across an issue I didn't realized before. The thing is that for instance: I want to delete an user and if a stop the debugging before the execution reaches that "delete" method, instead of stopping and NOT delete the user, it does delete user anyways.

Any bug related? What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you are refering to breakpoints? Can you provide a sample of your code and indicate where you are placing the breakpoints?

Comment: Nop, I'm refering to stop debbuging before actually update,insert,delete anything. I'm aware there's a workaround that would be to click on Terminate all. That solves this out but it should be enough by clicking on stop and I'm concerned why this is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/406kfbs1(v=vs.100).aspx:

"Stop Debugging terminates the process you are debugging **if the program was launched from Visual Studio**. If you attached to the process, instead of launching it from Visual Studio, **the process continues running**. If you want to terminate attached processes, you can terminate a single process from the Processes window or terminate all attached process with the Terminate All command."